# passport-jwt always return 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am trying to authenticate the nodejs api's using passport-jwt authentication strategy, but it always throws 401 unauthorized error. I tried various implementations but passport.authenticate function just doesn't seem to work.

Using below passport versions:
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",

Please see my code below:

Tried below options:

```
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()  
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization')  
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer')  
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')
```

But not working.

Tried looking into [passport-jwt 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897044/passport-jwt-401-unauthorized) and other links for reference as well.

app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const login = require('./routes/login');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/', login);

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server running on http://localhost:8000/'));
```

login.js file in route folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const passportref = require('./../controllers/passport');
const loginController = require('./../controllers/loginController');

router.post('/putemailregistration',loginController.putEmailregistration);
router.get('/login', passportref.authenticate,loginController.verifyLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

Passport.js file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const JWTStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const  ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const models = require('./../models');

const opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: 'incredible',
}
passport.use(new JWTStrategy(opts,async (payload, done) => {
 try {
     console.log(`inside jwt strategy func`);
     const user = models.Userabout.findById({
         where: { email: { [Op.eq]: payload.email } },
         attributes: ['id', 'email', 'password'],
     });
     console.log(`value of user: ${user}`);
     if (typeof user !== 'undefined' && user !== null) {
        return done(null, user);
     }
     else {
        return done(null, false);
     }
 } catch (err) {
     done(err, false);
 }
 }));


module.exports = {
    initialize: () => passport.initialize(),
    authenticate: passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
};
```

loginController.js file:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const models = require('./../models');
const saltRounds = 10;

module.exports.putEmailregistration = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      console.log(`inside put email registration`);

      if (req.body.email === null || req.body.password === null) {
          res.sendStatus(400).json('no data');
      } else {
         const emailregister = await models.Userdata.create({
             email: req.body.email,
             password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 
              bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds)),
         });
        const tokenid = jwt.sign({
            id: emailregister.id,
            email: emailregister.email,
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRETKEY,
        { expiresIn: 3600 });
        res.json({ success: true, token: 'bearer ' + tokenid });
     }
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(`error at put email registration: ${err}`);
   }
}


module.exports.verifyLogin = (req, res) => {
  console.log(`i managed to get here`);

  // console.log(`user: ${req.user}`);
 // res.send(req.user.email);
}
```

Comment: already posted plz check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897044/passport-jwt-401-unauthorized

Comment: Yes @Vijay, i have tried that. I have given a reference to that link as well in the question posted by me. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

After lot of debugging, i finally resolved the issue. Hope this might help someone

1. By mistake i was pointing out to a wrong model in passport.js file. It was Userdata instead of Userabout.
2. In loginController.js file i changed as below:
   const payload = { id: emailregister.id }
   const token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
3. Using below option worked well.
   jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer');

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you can manage it in your middle ware

```
function authorized(request, response, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false, }, async (error, token) => {
        if (error || !token) {
            response.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized Message' });
        } 
        try {
            console.log('token',token)
            const user = await User.findOne(
                {_id: token._id}
            );
            request.user = user;
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
        next();
    })(request, response, next);   
}

router.get(
  '/',
  authorized,
  trimRequest.all,
  user.getItems
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `expiresIn` value from the environment variable. The environment variable values will be of `String` type and If we pass a string value to `expiresIn`, it will be taken in milliseconds. So a value of 3600 was getting converted to 3 seconds and by the time I copy the token from the sign-in response to the auth header, it was getting expired.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#usage

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`passport.use('jwt',new JWTStrategy({opts},verify_callback(){})` in `passport.js`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was calling done(null) instead of done(null, jwtPayload) which lead to 401s

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: secret,
}, function (jwtPayload, done) {
  done(null, jwtPayload); // I was calling just done(null)
})).authenticate('jwt', { session: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many different problems which can lead to this issue.
In my case, it was a wrong format of the public key – the key has to be in PEM format:

```
const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyn2vP592Ju/iKXQW1DCrSTXyQXyo11Qed1SdzFWC+mRtdgioKibzYMBt2MfAJa6YoyrVNgOtGvK659MjHALtotPQGmis1VVvBeMFdfh+zyFJi8NPqgBTXz6bQfnu85dbxVAg95J+1Ud0m4IUXME1ElOyp1pi88+w0C6ErVcFCyEDS3uAajBY6vBIuPrlokbl6RDcvR9zX85s+R/s7JeP1XV/e8gbnYgZwxcn/6+7moHPDl4LqvVDKnDq9n4W6561s8zzw8EoAwwYXUC3ZPe2/3DcUCh+zTF2nOy8HiN808CzqLq1VeD13q9DgkAmBWFNSaXb6vK6RIQ9+zr2cwdXiwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
};
```

For debugging, it helps to add a callback as the third parameter to the `passport.authenticate()` Method:

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', 
  { session: false }, 
  (err, user, info, status) => { /* do some logging here */ })
```