# Passport Jwt Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Hello I was trying to implement passport-jwt on my webapp. But It wont work I've seen several same post and tried what they did but on my case it didnt worked.

here are some [Authenticating node API with passport-jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528377/authenticating-node-api-with-passport-jwt)

[passport local strategy not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690354/passport-local-strategy-not-getting-called)

[Passport-jwt Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858758/passport-jwt-unauthorized)

I've tried those and it didnt worked.
Here is my code on my passport.js

```
    var config = require('./config');

var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
module.exports =
    function(passport){
        var opts ={};
        opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
        opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
            passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,function(jwt_payload,done){
                console.log('HERE');
                console.log(jwt_payload);
                User.findOne({id:jwt_payload._id},function(err,user){
                    if(err)
                        return done(err,false);
                    if(user)
                        return done(null,user);
                    else
                        return done(null,false);
                        })

                    }));
            };
```

It wont even reach the `console.log('HERE');`

and this is how I generate my token

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    User.findUser(username,function(err,user){
        if(err) return res.json({success:false,msg:"Error"});
        if(!user) return res.json({success:false,msg:"No Such user"});
        //res.json(user);
        console.log(user);
        if(user){
            User.comparePass(password,user.password,function(err,IsMatched){
                if(err) return res.json({success:false,msg:'error});
                if(!IsMatched) return  res.json({success:false,msg:"wrong password"});
                if(IsMatched){
                    var token = jwt.sign(user.toObject(),config.secret,{expiresIn:604800});
                    res.json({success:true,token:'JWT '+ token,
                            user:{
                                name:user.name,
                                username:user.username,
                                password:user.password,
                                email:user.email,
                                contact:user.contact,
                                address:user.address
                            }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and here is what im trying to access

```
router.get('/profile',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({user:req.user});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out.

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')
```

instead of

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
```