# passport.use method not calling in node js using passport-local strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, passport.js

When calling login and submit form the **use.authenticate()** method is not executing and also not showing any error message.

**Server.js** file:

```
const passport=require('passport');
const Strategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new Strategy(
    function (username,password,done) {
        User.findOne({username:username,password:password},(err,res)=>{
            if(err)throw err;
            displayName=username;
            console.log(res);
            return done(null,res);
        })
    }
));

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
    done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user,done)=>{
    done(null,user);
});

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local',{
            failureRedirect:'/loginForm',
            successRedirect:'/'
        }
));
```

**login.hbs** file:

```
<article class="article">
    <h1>login</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        Username<input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password<input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: This will help you out. [Go through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253353/5995973)

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize passport in other part of your code?

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Yes I have initialize passport